# Extension Everything. Зачем оно нужно?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-8.0

[Наткнулся](https://adrientorris.github.io/csharp/what-i-get-from-the-preview-of-csharp-8-with-Mads-Torgersen.html) на еще одно новшество новой редакции языка под названием `Extension Everything` (Имхо спорное).

С точки зрения синтаксиса, что не нужно иметь статический класс, вроде, прикольно.

Однако теперь, как я понимаю, позволяетется,  расширять абсолютно все:

```
extension MyPersonExtension extends Person
{
    public int CountFingers()
    {
        this. // it call the current instance of Person
    }
}

extension MyPersonExtension extends Person
{
    public int NumberOfFingers()
    {
        get { ... }
    }
}

extension MyPersonExtension extends Person
{
    static int ... // You can add static things
}
```

Как видно в примере добавляются новые поля в класс.

Собственно, вопрос: Зачем это нужно, если в таком случае правильнее сделать наследование?

Если эта штука позволяет еще и запечатанные классы расширять, то это же противоречит инкапсуляции..

Comment: [sarcasm]Ещё немного и дойдем до наследования через extensions[/sarcasm]

Comment: @tym32167, да ладно, просто решили сделать норм расширители :-) а имплементацию интерфейса прилеплять любому классу - вообще киллер фича

Comment: @Grundy ну что вы, дайте побрюжжать, мне же после подобных нововведений придется новые ООП фокусы учить )

Comment: Это не новшество языка а только обсуждаемая тогда в 2018 фича, спустя пять лет её так и нет не в одной версии c#

Answer (score 7):

#### Зачем это нужно?

Это логичное продолжение подхода extension, позволяя описывать в расширениях не только методы, но и свойства, а так же статические поля.

Как и в случае с extensions сейчас - исходный класс **НЕ** меняется. Так что никаких проблем с инкапсуляцией нет, как их нет сейчас с использованием extensions.

---

Кроме того, в вопросе не упомянуто еще одна возможность: указывать что класс имплементирует нужный интерфейс

```
extension MyPersonExtension extends Person : IEmployee // The Person class implements now the IEmployee interface in your assembly
{
    [ ... ]
}
```

Comment: Вроде, там и конструкторы можно свои объявлять. А разве this не значит, что мы получим доступ к внутреннему устройству класса?

Comment: @iluxa1810, откуда предположение про конструкторы? `this` - играет ту же роль, что и в extensions, когда указывается первым параметром.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/11159 вот тут в 2016 году пишут, что сначала разрешать не будут.

Comment: @iluxa1810, на самом деле ничего страшного в _таких_ "конструкторах" нет. По сути это просто обертка для вызова обычного конструктора, с нужными параметрами.

Comment: А эти расширения как то повлияют на тип класса? Неужели тип будет меняться в зависимости от наличия таких расширений?

Comment: @Monk _Как и в случае с extensions сейчас - исходный класс **НЕ** меняется._

Comment: И как тогда будет работать Person is IEmployee например? Вернёт false?

Comment: @Monk, должен вернуть `true`, если подключено это расширение :-)

Comment: Пока звучит подозрительно, в целом. Тогда получится, что оно работает например в рамках сборки или ещё что.

Comment: @Monk, собственно поведение точно такое же как и сейчас у расширений

Comment: Расширения сейчас - только методы. У них нет никаких проблем с тем, чтобы построить правильно вызов (можно даже инлайнить). Вычислимые свойства - легко, ибо это тоже методы, а вот интерфейсы... что если у меня read-write свойство в интерфейсе -- где данные то хранятся? Подозрительно =)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85558/discussion-between-grundy-and-monk).